# Create a horizontal scrolling div without defining a specific width?

Tags: scroll

Im trying to create a horizontally scrolling gallery but I would like to avoid defining the width on the div. Someone else is touching the html - I want her to be able to drop in as many li as possible without having to touch the css and redefining the width.

The mock site is here: rachelbeen.com/Carmen.

Safari recognizes where the content ends and stops the horizontal scroll - but firefox maintains that extra space as defined by the width:6600px; on the #gallery ul. How do I stop that from happening?

Would like to avoid plugins if possible and use only CSS.

Thanks,

-Rachel

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I tried this:

```
#full{margin:0 auto; overflow:auto; height:100%; width:1050px;}
// width is just for controlling the viewport.

#holder{float:left; margin-right:-30000px;}

.box{float:left; margin:2px;}
```

and **HTML** should be like:

```
<div id="full">
    <div id="holder">
        <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
        <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

add many DIVs as you want and it'll make more space for you boxes without giving it a specific width. I hope it helps you.